# bad access physics field crashes application SWIFT, XCODE

Tags: ios, swift, exc-bad-access

Hey I have a world/Scene with a man in it so I decided to make a physics field to act as gravity. so I'm able to code it in no problem using swift but then I ran the app and it keeps giving me bad access. With out these lines of code my app/scenekit game runs smoothly any help. Please see the image attached Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJQ8S.png)

Code:

```
    // I declared field owner up at the top here
    class GameViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate, SKPhysicsContactDelegate, SKSceneDelegate, SCNSceneRendererDelegate, SCNPhysicsContactDelegate{

       var fieldOwner = SCNNode()

       override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()

         //Force field to act as Gravity 

         fieldOwner = SCNNode()
         fieldOwner.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: -5, z: -5)

         let field: SCNPhysicsField = SCNPhysicsField.radialGravityField()
         field.halfExtent = SCNVector3Make(100, 100, 100)
         field.minimumDistance = 20.0
         field.falloffExponent = 0

         self.fieldOwner.physicsField!.strength = 0.0
         self.fieldOwner.physicsField = field

         scnView.scene!.rootNode.addChildNode(fieldOwner)
     }
  }
```

Comment: Try using the debugger.  It should tell you which line the bad access occurred on.

Comment: ok I did its the physics strength line of code. I attached an image to this question

Comment: Is something nil on that line?

Comment: Maybe its the way Im coding in the force field idk but I don't know any other way to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are accessing `self.fieldOwner.physicsField` before setting it. Try setting the strength on your local `field` variable instead:

Change

```
self.fieldOwner.physicsField!.strength = 0.0
```

To

```
field.strength = 0.0
```